# How do I get embedded elements in text with nokogiri?

Tags: nokogiri

Now that's my html:

```
<div class="cardtextbox"><i>(<img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=BR&amp;type=symbol" alt="Black or Red" align="absbottom" /> can be paid with either <img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=B&amp;type=symbol" alt="Black" align="absbottom" /> or <img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=R&amp;type=symbol" alt="Red" align="absbottom" />.)</i></div><div class="cardtextbox"><img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=3&amp;type=symbol" alt="3" align="absbottom" /><img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=B&amp;type=symbol" alt="Black" align="absbottom" />, Discard a card: Target creature gets -2/-2 until end of turn.</div><div class="cardtextbox"><img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=3&amp;type=symbol" alt="3" align="absbottom" /><img src="/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=R&amp;type=symbol" alt="Red" align="absbottom" />: Put a 2/1 red Goblin creature token with haste onto the battlefield. Exile it at the beginning of the next end step.</div></div>
```

And what I'd like to get:

```
[
 ["(B/R can be paid with either B or R.)"],
 ["3 B, Discard a card", "Target creature gets -2/-2 until end of turn"],
 ["3 R",                 "Put a 2/1 red Goblin creature token with haste onto the battlefield. Exile it at the beginning of the next end step."]
]
```

Mapping from Red => R is done via `colorhash`. The Red comes form the `img` tag, `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `colorhash` is, or how it's relevant to this question, but here's something that should get you close. If you really want a nested array of answers, you'll have to define a recursive function to process a node and determine for yourself if a node is a leaf or not.

```
require 'nokogiri'
colorhash = {
  'Red'          => 'R',
  'Black'        => 'B',
  'Black or Red' => 'B/R'
}

h = Nokogiri::HTML html_from_question

# Replace all images with alt text, possibly transformed
h.xpath('//img[@alt]').each{ |i| i.swap( colorhash[i['alt']] || i['alt']) }

require 'pp'
pp h.css('.cardtextbox').map(&:text)

#=> ["(B/R can be paid with either B or R.)",
#=>  "3B, Discard a card: Target creature gets -2/-2 until end of turn.",
#=>  "3R: Put a 2/1 red Goblin creature token with haste onto the battlefield. Exile it at the beginning of the next end step."]
```